# Node JS - How can I print something to an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

i have a question about working with Node JS, AJAX and so on. I am trying to get a JSON file content to appear in my HTML page. I can save new objects into my JSON file, but i can't seem to find a good method to put them in the desired HTML page. here is my codes so far.

```html
//Vai buscar a express library para utilização do servidor local;
var express = require("express");
//app vai ouvir requests de HTTP
var app = express();
//Require do body parser
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//fs requirement - para json
var fs = require("fs")

//Tem que se definir isto se quisermos ter directorias,assim nao precisamos de meter o caminho absoluto todas as vezes
app.use(express.static('public'))
//Utilização do express do bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
//

//Mandar o fs ler o ficheiro (transformar em JSON), e depois converter o JSON para uma variável para que possa ser utilizada
var fsRead = fs.readFileSync("alunos.json")
var alunos = JSON.parse(fsRead)


//Aqui vai ou direccionar para um página,atraves do send file do res, ou imprimir mensagens com o send
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("/public/index.html");
});

//GET da criação de um novo aluno.
app.get('/formulario_get', function(req, res) {
    var response = {
        nome:"ola", //com o GET os parâmetros vêm por querystring
        morada:"morada"
        };
        console.log(response);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
})
//POST do formulário do aluno
    //app.post("no formulário, na parte do action, meter aqui o nome para o servidor saber qual o pedido feito")
app.post('/processarFormulario', function(req, res, next){
    var aluno = {
        numero: req.body.numero,
        nome: req.body.nome, 
        morada: req.body.morada,
        notafinal: req.body.notafinal
    }
    alunos.push(aluno)
    console.log(alunos)
    res.redirect("index.html")
});
//vai imprimir para a consola em que port está a ouvir
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log(alunos)
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", server.address().address, server.address().port)
});
```

this is the server atm (Sorry for the variables and comments being in Portuguese, this is for school purposes)

**Code Updated for English Purposes(took out the portuguese comments too)**

```html
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var fs = require("fs")


app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


var fsRead = fs.readFileSync("alunos.json")
var students = JSON.parse(fsRead)


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("/public/index.html");
});


app.get('/formulario_get', function(req, res) {
    var response = {
        name:"ola", //com o GET os parâmetros vêm por querystring
        address:"morada"
        };
        console.log(response);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
})

app.post('/processarFormulario', function(req, res, next){
    var student = {
        number: req.body.number,
        name: req.body.name, 
        address: req.body.address,
        grade: req.body.grade
    }
    students.push(student)
    console.log(students)
    res.redirect("index.html")
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log(students)
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", server.address().address, server.address().port)
});
```

Comment: Can you please translate some of your variable names and comments to English? it will help a lot to help you :-)

Comment: Given that you are using express, why not use a template engine like `pug`? Check out https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: I updated the code with english variables

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static HTML files. Write templates instead.

You are using Express. [This is covered in the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

There are [many different template engines](https://www.slant.co/topics/51/~best-javascript-templating-engines) to choose from.

Comment: seems easy enough,but they said to create html page and use an onload event to load the list and display it(in a DOM table,but i will try to solve that after)

Comment: @Kami — That's a terrible idea, but if you really want to do that then the keyword to search for is Ajax. It's too broad to cover here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first comment, I would personally recommend EJS. EJS looks and works just like HTML and it also supports sending variable to the webpage when rendering. Ex:

**index.js**

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index', {name: Jakeb});
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<script>
    var name = <%= JSON.parse(name) %>;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
<script>
<p id='name'></p>
```

or

```
<p id='name'><%= JSON.parse(name) %></p>
```

That would look like:

Jakeb

On the client side.